# Cookies setted by JavaScript in one page not showing in another page

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have created a cookie in JavaScript. I can see and use the cookie in that file. I am not able to see and use the same cookie in another page in the same domain.  What could be the problem?

This is the code

```
// Code for set Cookie

        // Code for set Cookie
    function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
                {
                var exdate=new Date();
                exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
                var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
                document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
                }
    //Function to call setcookie. In this function I cookie is adding successfully and I can alert the value of the cartcounter cookie. It will be increment one by one for each click 
    function makeSure(skey,name){
                    var cartcounter=getCookie("cartcounter");
                    cartcounter=parseInt(cartcounter);
                    chk=0;
                    for(var i=1;i<=cartcounter;i++){
                        var ckey = getCookie(i+"_skey");
                        if(ckey==skey){
                            chk++;
                        }
                    }
                    if(chk==0){ 

                        cartcounter=cartcounter+1;
                        setCookie("cartcounter",cartcounter,365);   
                        setCookie(cartcounter+"_skey",skey,365);
                        setCookie(cartcounter+"_name",name,365);
                        setCookie(cartcounter+"_val",$("#cnt_"+skey).val(),365);
                        alert(name+" added to your cart successfully.. ");
                    }
                    else
                        alert("You have already added "+name+" item to cart ");


            }
    // This is the code in another page to view the cookie. But it show only 0
            var cartcounter=getCookie("cartcounter");
            alert("Counter="+cartcounter);
```

Comment: post some code, maybe you did something wrong ..

Comment: Thanks for your time Mihai, I have posted the code. Please take a look in it . Thanks

Comment: And where is `getCookie` function ?

Comment: function getCookie(c_name)
   {
   
   var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
   for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
   {
     x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
     y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
     x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
     if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
     }
   }

Comment: I have tried to update the question I have posted with the getcookie function, but unfortunately , stackoverflow not allowing me to update the question. Thats y added it as a comment. Thanks

Comment: Works for me, are you sure you included `getCookie` in second page? What cookie you are unable to read?

Comment: 'cartcounter', I am not able to read cartcounter. It always showing 0.

Comment: that doesn't mean it doesn't work ... maybe some fault in your `cartcounter`

Answer (score 2):

1. Set your `path`. If your created cookie is inside of one path `/features/feature1/`, and you're trying to access it from a different "folder": `/items/item1/` it won't exist.
   So set `path` to `/` if you want it to be accessible on every page in the same domain, regardless of where in the pathing hierarchy it is.
2. speaking of domains, if your first page is on `www.mysite.com` and your second page is on `shop.mysite.com` or some other subdomain, then the cookie also won't be available, so set your domain to be equal to `.mysite.com`, which will cover any page where the domain is `_____.mysite.com`

If you never, ever need #2 then don't bother setting the domain.
But if you ever do use subdomains then remember that.